# Skrollr doesn't work with 100% height on html and body

Tags: javascript, css, skrollr

In my setup, skrollr seems to fail if I set the body and html height to 100%.
I have the following css:

```
html,body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
```

and the following js to initialize skrollr:

```
s = skrollr.init({
  forceHeight: false,
  smoothScrolling: false
});
```

When I remove the height on the html and body, everything works fine, but I would really need it for my project...
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue of skrollr: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/347

Did you try the `height: 100% !important;`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. If I do this, skrollr just stops working silently

Comment: Did you try on both and separately html, body?

Comment: I need to make it work with 100% on both html and body, since I want to use min-height 100% on the main wrapping div (to position the footer absolutely on the bottom)

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Same issue. V buggy library :(